# Kivy Buildozer fails to build apk, command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" d

Tags: android, ubuntu, kivy, adk

I'm trying to build an APK using Kivy and Buildozer, and when I run "buildozer android debug," I receive this error as a response:

```
a
./distribute.sh: line 371: test: too many arguments
./distribute.sh: line 372: test: too many arguments
./distribute.sh: line 373: test: too many arguments
./distribute.sh: line 374: test: too many arguments
./distribute.sh: line 377: $SRC_PATH/default.properties: ambiguous redirect
./distribute.sh: line 378: $SRC_PATH/local.properties: ambiguous redirect
cp: cannot create regular file ‘x/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/.git/objects/pack/pack-b89e3f872ff0b0fbbaa9c0f1182451f8506241dc.idx’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘x/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/.git/objects/pack/pack-b89e3f872ff0b0fbbaa9c0f1182451f8506241dc.pack’: Permission denied
cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘/home/tom/Dropbox/Work’, into itself, ‘Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/Work’
cp: will not create hard link x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: cannot stat ‘Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/blacklist.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
cp: will not create hard link ‘x’ to directory ‘y’
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "pongtest"
```

It seems like it's going through a weird redirect, but it's unfortunately returning an unspecific error message, so if anyone has any ideas on what it might be, they'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the bulldozer.spec:

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = Pong Test

# (str) Package name
package.name = pongtest

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version = 1.2.0

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = 

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters = 

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =
[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2
```

Comment: Is this the first time you've used buildozer, or has it worked in the past? Assuming the former, could you post your buildozer.spec?

Comment: You should edit the original post to include the buildozer.spec instead of sending people to a sketchy file upload site.

Comment: @brousch Yeah, sorry about that, I added it to the original post.

Comment: You have some odd errors I've not seen before. Make sure your Buildozer and python-for-android are up to date, you're not running on a remotely mounted drive, and not running on an encrypted drive.

Comment: @brousch Yep, I'm not on a remote or encrypted drive, and I just updated and tried again, getting the same error readout.

Answer (score 1):

These are permission problems! When I chmod 777 the whole source dir things work (I do not recommend that as a fix, though :) )

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Kubuntu, resulting in the error:

```
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "kivyapptest"
```

I was building on a Kubuntu guest VM, but my files were on a shared folder of my host (my Macbook Pro).

After copying `buildozer.spec` and `main.py` to a folder in my Kubuntu home folder, and rebuilding (with `sudo` permissions ofcourse), I finally ended up with my .apk file.

Comment: NEVER run buildozer with sudo. NEVER.

Answer (score 0):

Move your files to your home folder ( where deployed package will be stored ). This is strange, but it worked for me - I moved the main.py and spec to Macintosh HD, where deploy is created.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and figured out that it was due to there being a space and parenthesizes in the name of my parent directory:

Works: "example_copy"
Doesnt work: "example (copy)"